# Bash shell don't recognize else statement

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, redhat

I am trying to build a script that asks the user to enter the file size and path, if the file size is bigger then the limit the file should bd delete, the problem is even if the file is smaller then the entered value, the script delete that file anyway, I think there is an error in my Else statement

and I already tried "https://www.shellcheck.net/"  and give me this error and I didn't know how to solve it 
`if [ "$SIZE" -gt "$limit" ];
^-- SC2154: limit is referenced but not assigned.`

```
#!/bin/bash
 limit="$1"
shift 1 
for file in "$@"; do
SIZE="$(stat --format="%s" "$file")"
if [ "$SIZE" -gt "$limit" ];
then
echo "$file is $SIZE bytes. Deleting..; -rm $file"
 else 
echo "file is smaller then limit no delete"
 fi
 done
```

Edit: I removed 'read' and now I get this error '[: -gt: unary operator expected '
and even if the file size is bigger then the entered value its go directly to else statement

Comment: What is `read -i limit="$1"` supposed to do? How are you calling your script?

Comment: `read` is for setting a variable from terminal input, `$1` is for accessing a command-line argument.

Comment: now I get this error  [: -gt: unary operator expected
and even if the file size is bigger then the entered value its  go directly to else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShellCheck is on the right track: `limit` is indeed not being assigned, because your `read` statement is invalid. Your script therefore always thinks `limit=0` and therefore that all files should be deleted.

Instead of

```
read -i limit="$1"
```

you should just do

```
limit="$1"
```

Here is the complete script with this change:

```
#!/bin/bash
limit=$1
shift 1
for file in "$@"; do
SIZE="$(stat --format="%s" "$file")"
if [ "$SIZE" -gt "$limit" ];
then
echo "$file is $SIZE bytes. Deleting..; -rm $file"
 else
echo "file is smaller then limit no delete"
 fi
 done
```

And here's an example of running it:

```
$ ls -l big small
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 505 May 19 15:01 big
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 495 May 19 15:01 small

$ ./myscript 500 big small
big is 505 bytes. Deleting..; -rm big
file is smaller then limit no delete
```

Comment: now I get this error [: -gt: unary operator expected and even if the file size is bigger then the entered value its go directly to else statement –

Comment: I have posted your complete script with this change in place, plus an example of running it that shows both branches. Can you please try the same thing?

Comment: The error `[: -gt: unary operator expected` would show up if you did `if [ $SIZE -gt $limit ]` (without double quotes).  It should not arise if the variables are properly quoted.

Comment: done its work now , my mistake was the  double quotes